# How can I disable meta tags provided by the Metatag module for a custom route?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I have created a custom module for displaying the players information. Module will create dynamic pages and each page will display players stats. With the help of the following links, I was able to add meta tags to my module.

1. [How to add meta tag in head](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-head-head-section/283609#283609)
2. [Adding meta tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-head-head-section)

Since each of the page generated by my module for separate meta information, I was not able to use page_attachement_hooks. Using the above links, I was able to add meta information in my controller itself.

But, I am using Meta tag drupal module for generating meta information for other pages. Now I am getting multiple meta tags with same property name. Global configurations of meta tag module is displaying along with my meta tags.

I read in some blog that if multiple meta tags found with same property, few crawlers will ignore them. How do I keep only my meta tags?

I saw [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223103/how-to-override-default-meta-tags) which says how to override the meta tags. But there the code has to be placed in the module and it will be static. I wanted dynamic meta tags for each page. How will I achieve it?

Here is my code.

PlayerController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\player\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal;

class PlayerController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content($player) {
    $result = [];
    /* --------------
     code logic here 
    ------------------ */
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $result,
      '#attached' => [
        'html_head' => [
        [
         [
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => [
            'property' => 'og:description',
            'content' => $result->player_details,
          ],
        ],
        'player',
      ],
    ],
  ],
    ];
  }

}
```

For reference, I am adding [link to my old question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/dynamic-meta-tags-and-description-in-custom-pages?noredirect=1#comment359511_288144) regarding how to add meta tags in dynamic module. It have more codes in case you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** – @AlfredArmstrong pointed me to [the hooks provided by the Metatag module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/metatag/blob/8.x-1.x/metatag.api.php) itself. And there's [`hook_metatags_alter()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/metatag/blob/8.x-1.10/metatag.api.php#L38-43) you can implement to completely disable all meta tags added by the Metatag module. Much shorter than my original answer.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_metatags_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_metatags_alter(array &$metatags, array &$context) {

  // Exclude meta tags on 'player' route.
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'player') {
    $metatags = NULL;
  }
}
```

---

**Original answer** – I've had similar problems [before](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263094/15055). You can override or unset meta tags added by the Metatag module implementing [`hook_page_attachments_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.7.x) like in the following example.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

  // Check for the route you want to override.
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'player') {

    // An array of tags you want to unset.
    $unset = [
      'description' => 1,
      'abstract' => 1,
      'keywords' => 1,
    ];

    $meta_tags = $attachments['#attached']['html_head'];
    foreach ($meta_tags as $key => $meta_tag) {

      // And now unset them.
      if (isset($unset[$meta_tag[1]])) {

        unset($attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason not to use a metatag hook? https://git.drupalcode.org/project/metatag/blob/8.x-1.x/metatag.api.php Looks like hook_metatags_attachments_alter() would be the one to use.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong – Oh yes, I thought there must be some hook for that. But I didn't look thoroughly enough. I will check that out later and update my answer accordingly. Or you provide that in a new answer.

Comment: No, go ahead, though would also be worth pointing out that the hook implementation could be used to set the desired values rather than removing the ones from metatag. Might be cleaner.